# What does it take to earn the International Certificate of Competence?

Tags: sailing

What does it take to pass the [ICC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Competence)? Must you be willing to sail through the Mediterranean or hold a skipper license?

> An International Certificate of Competence (ICC) is a certificate
> which may be issued to anyone who has successfully completed certain
> national boating licenses or has successfully passed an examination to
> prove the necessary competence for pleasure craft operation.
>
> In very
> general terms an ICC is required for the inland waterways of Europe
> and for inland and coastal waters of Mediterranean countries. For the
> coastal waters of Northern Europe the ICC is generally not required,
> however to all of these generalisations there are exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the International Yacht Training [ICC page](http://iytworld.com/courses.php?bp=571):

> - Completed ICC Application Form
> - Jpeg format headshot photograph
> - Scanned copy of passport or national identification
> - Scanned ICC Examination Form completed by the IYT Worldwide partner school that conducted the examination.
> - CEVNI Test - if completed (this is only required for inland waterways such as the French canals)

and

> **What skills and Knowledge are required to obtain an ICC?** To receive an ICC, candidates are required to prove competency in
> handling a boat with sufficient knowledge of navigation procedures,
> pilotage, safety procedures and the International Regulations for the
> prevention of collisions at sea. This can be done by examination or by
> evaluating existing boating qualifications. The examination can be
> taken on either a powerboat or sailboat depending on the endorsement
> required and usually takes about 4-6 hours.
>
> **Syllabus**
>
> **1) Preparation for sea**
>
> Checklist and mechanical check
>
> **2) Short Passage**
>
> Each candidate executes a short pre-planned passage as skipper
>
> Testing of the following is required:
>
> - Coming alongside / berthing / unberthing
> - Man overboard recovery
> - 360 degree turn
> - Navigation skills
> - 3 point turn
> - Handling under sail ( for sail endorsement)
> - Handling under power ( for power endorsement)
>
> **3) Theory test**
>
> - Collision regulations
> - Navigation lights
> - Shapes and sounds
> - Bouyage (IALA A & B)
> - Harbour pilotage
> - VHF Radio
> - Variation & deviation
> - Chartwork /symbols & abbreviations
> - Tides- height of tide and drying height
> - Basic position fixing
> - Weather
> - Course to steer to counteract tide or current
> - Set & drift / leeway
> - Pilotage- required for coastal knowledge